# Using Regex.Split in c#

Tags: c#, regex, split

So i have a string that contains snowflake columns and i want to split the string to each column, I’m trying to use Regex to do this as it split string won't work in this situation. The string pattern i have tried is

```
string pattern = @"([^\s]*\s[^\s]*),"
```

though this pattern splits after the second consecutive space. Im not sure how to split it just after the alias. I am also using .net core 3.1. Any help would be appreciated..

current snowflake datacolumn string:

```
string columns = "nvl(u.\"Country\",'#N/A') \"Country\",u.\"CreatedDate\" \"CreatedDate\",nvl(u.\"Email\",'#N/A') \"Email\",u.\"LastModifiedDate\" \"LastModifiedDate\",nvl(u.\"Name\",'#N/A') \"Name\"";
```

expected output:
nvl(u."Country",'#N/A') "Country"
u."CreatedDate" "CreatedDate"
nvl(u."Email",'#N/A') "Email"
u."LastModifiedDate" "LastModifiedDate"
nvl(u."Name",'#N/A') "Name"

Comment: You are probably looking for [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches), not Regex.Split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=\s""\w+""),");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cs%22%5Cw%2B%22%29%2C&i=nvl%28u.%22Country%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Country%22%2Cu.%22CreatedDate%22%20%22CreatedDate%22%2Cnvl%28u.%22Email%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Email%22%2Cu.%22LastModifiedDate%22%20%22LastModifiedDate%22%2Cnvl%28u.%22Name%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Name%22). *Details*:

- `(?<=\s"\w+")` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with a whitespace, `"`, one or more word chars, `"`
- `,` - a comma.

[image]

Another idea is to extract the matches with

```cs
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b(?:nvl\([^()]*\)|u\.""[^""]*"")\s+""[^""]*""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3Anvl%5C%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%7Cu%5C.%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29%5Cs%2B%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22&i=nvl%28u.%22Country%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Country%22%2Cu.%22CreatedDate%22%20%22CreatedDate%22%2Cnvl%28u.%22Email%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Email%22%2Cu.%22LastModifiedDate%22%20%22LastModifiedDate%22%2Cnvl%28u.%22Name%22%2C%27%23N%2FA%27%29%20%22Name%22).

[image]

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:nvl\([^()]*\)|u\."[^"]*")` - `nvl(...)` or `u."..."`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `"[^"]*"` - `"`, zero or more non-`"`s, and a `"`.

Comment: Thank You !! , that makes sense i actually tried something different which seemed to work.  string pattern =  @"([^\s]*\s[\\\\""].*?[\\\\""]),"; Although the implementation you have is a lot more cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group (group 1) and exclude the comma in the second part after matching the space. To match all parts, you can match either a comma or the end of the string at the end of the pattern.

This part `[^\s]*` can be written as `\S*`

```
(\S*\s[^\s,]*)(?:,|$)
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S*\s[^\s,]*` Match optional non whitespace chars, match a whitespace char and match optional non whitespace chars except a comme
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:,|$)` Match either a comma or assert the end of the string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cS*%5cs%5b%5e%5cs%2c%5d*%29%28%3f%3a%2c%7c%24%29&i=nvl%28u.%22Country%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Country%22%2cu.%22CreatedDate%22+%22CreatedDate%22%2cnvl%28u.%22Email%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Email%22%2cu.%22LastModifiedDate%22+%22LastModifiedDate%22%2cnvl%28u.%22Name%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Name%22)

[image]

For example

```
string pattern = @"(\S*\s[^\s,]*)(?:,|$)";
string input = @"nvl(u.""Country"",'#N/A') ""Country"",u.""CreatedDate"" ""CreatedDate"",nvl(u.""Email"",'#N/A') ""Email"",u.""LastModifiedDate"" ""LastModifiedDate"",nvl(u.""Name"",'#N/A') ""Name""";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
nvl(u."Country",'#N/A') "Country"
u."CreatedDate" "CreatedDate"
nvl(u."Email",'#N/A') "Email"
u."LastModifiedDate" "LastModifiedDate"
nvl(u."Name",'#N/A') "Name"
```

---

A bit more specific pattern using `+` to match 1 or more characters and match word characters between double quotes:

```
 (\S+\s"\w+")(?:,|$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cS%2b%5cs%22%5cw%2b%22%29%28%3f%3a%2c%7c%24%29&i=nvl%28u.%22Country%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Country%22%2cu.%22CreatedDate%22+%22CreatedDate%22%2cnvl%28u.%22Email%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Email%22%2cu.%22LastModifiedDate%22+%22LastModifiedDate%22%2cnvl%28u.%22Name%22%2c%27%23N%2fA%27%29+%22Name%22)